# Tailwind plugin class not found by @apply in app.scss

Tags: sass, tailwind-css, sveltekit

I'm working on a SvelteKit project; I've installed Tailwind and its DaisyUI plugin.

Using `@apply input` (a class from DaisyUI) in `app.scss` got me the following error:

`The 'input' class does not exist. If 'input' is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a '@layer' directive.`

Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can @apply to base TW classes only.
You can extend the classes in [tailwind.config.js](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles) or create [@layer components](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#using-apply-with-per-component-css) (or utilities...) inside .css

Comment: I missed I can only `@apply`TW classes. Thanks!